# the correct way to map identity base class with fluent api in ef core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api, ef-core-2.0

How is it supposed that i have to map the identity base class in EF Core if i want to entity be a primary key

I based in the project example of Vaughn Vernon ([example](https://github.com/VaughnVernon/IDDD_Samples_NET)) in this example him create a identity class like that:

```
public class ProductId : Identity
{
    public ProductId()
        : base()
    {
    }

    public ProductId(string id)
        : base(id)
    {
    }
}
```

and here is his implementation

```
public class Product {
  public ProductId ProductId {get; private set;}
}
```

My doubt is what is the correct way to map this? because i was try to map directically `modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().HasKey(p => p.ProductId);` but in migration EF Core tell me

> Cannot call Property for the property 'ProductId' on entity type 'Product' because it is configured as a navigation property.
>   Property can only be used to configure scalar properties.

i know that i can use OwnsOne but if i do that way i will don't create a primary key of identity, right?

Answer (score 0):

Your objects should look like the following

Object Class

```
public class Product
  {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    ...
  }
```

By default entity framework will look for an object named Id or ProductId and will automatically make it the primary key. So while it is not needed to set the key in the DbContext you are able to do it. I generally do not set the Id unless it is a different name.

DbContext

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
      base.OnModelCreating(builder);
      builder.Entity<Product>().HasKey(x => x.Id);
    }
```

** UPDATE **

If you are not setting the DbSets in your db context, then you indeed will have to set the id in the OnModelCreating call so the migrations will recognize the object as an Entity object

Comment: Yea but i want to know if is posible extract the id from the identity base class and tell to EF that the ProductId has inside the id
I did a some trick, i put a property `private string Id { get {return productId.id} set { ProductId = new ProductId(id); }}` but i don't know i feel that i do all wrong